# Integral with constant u-substitution

Tags: integration

This is a simple integral.

$$
\int \frac{1}{3x}dx
$$

with an equally simple solution of

$$
\frac{1}{3}\ln|x| +c
$$

My question is that if you chose to use u-substitution and used u = 3x, the solution appears to work out as follow:

$$
\int \frac{1}{u} \frac {du}{3}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{3} \ln|3x|+c
$$

which seems correct as well. Is this in fact correct? The 2 graphs appear nothing alike.

Comment: both answers are correct and are the same, just write $C:=\ln 3+K$

Comment: By the way, the graphs are actually [pretty similar](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(log%7Cx%7C)%2F3,+(log%7C3x%7C)%2F3).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's the same since you have a constant of integration..
$$ \frac{1}{3} \ln|3x|+c= \frac 13\ln |x|+ \underbrace{\frac{1}{3} \ln|3|+c}_{ \text { is a constant } }=\frac{1}{3} \ln|x|+K$$

Comment: Thanks guys. Completely forgot about expanding the log.

Comment: yw @Deeves its the constant of integration that absorb the $ \log(3)$

Comment: Good points are living here! +1

Comment: thank you @ResidentDementor

Answer (score 10):

Hint: use that $$\ln(3x)=\ln(3)+\ln(x)$$

Answer (score 6):

If you choose the substitution $u=3x\implies du=3\,dx$, then $$\int\frac{dx}{3x}=\int\frac{3\,dx}{3\cdot3x}=\frac13\int\frac{du}{3u}=\frac13\ln|3u|+C=\frac13\ln3+\frac13\ln|u|+C=\color{red}{\frac13\ln|u|+C_1}$$ where $C_1=\frac13\ln3+C$ is another constant.